# Avoid entires being duplicated when using Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, json, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) in order to scrape EPG data for a personal project.

Currently the code scrapes each channel's data, and dumps it in a json file, I'm filtering all the data scraped by adding my own `$Channels` which limits the data scraped to only items I specifically request along with adding my own stream links using the following...

```
$channels = array(
        "ITV1 London" => "URL 1",
);
```

---

I can't figure out a way to avoid each channel's data from being duplicated in the outputted json file. As I need to request the `$channels` so I can filter what data's presented in the final output along with my own links being added to the final output.

```
if ($channels[$channel_name]) {
            $channel = array();
```

---

**Full Code**

[Screenshot of working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeqPr.png)

```
<?php

// Include the php dom parser
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Create DOM from URL or file

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://tv24.co.uk");
$html=curl_exec($curl);
$dom = new simple_html_dom(null, true, true);
$html=$dom->load($html, true, true);

$channels = array(
    "ITV1 London" => "URL 1"
);

$data = array();

foreach($html->find('section div') as $ul)
{
    foreach($ul->find('div.channel-wrapper') as $show) {

        $channel_name = $show->find('h2.name')[0]->plaintext;

        if ($channels[$channel_name]) {
            $channel = array();

            $channel['channel'] =$channel_name ;
            $channel['logo'] = $show->find('span.logo img')[0]->src;
            $channel['thumb'] = explode("'", $show->find('div.program')[0]->style)[1];
            $channel['on-now'] = $show->find('span.title a')[0]->plaintext;
            $channel['on-now-time'] = $show->find('span.time')[0]->plaintext;
            $channel['on-now-description'] = $show->find('span.description')[0]->plaintext;
            $channel['up-next'] = $show->find('span.title a')[1]->plaintext;
            $channel['up-next-time'] = $show->find('span.time')[1]->plaintext;
            $channel['stream'] = $channels[$channel_name];

            $data['data'][] = $channel;
        }

    }

}
echo json_encode($data);

$myFile = "output.json";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("error");
$stringData = json_encode($data);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use an associative array for the channel

```
$data['data'][$channel_name] = $channel;
```

you'll just overwrite the previous entry with the new one. A smarter way would be to keep an array of channels and skip processing onces you've already done.

```
$channels[] = $channel_name;

....

if (in_array($channel_name, $channels))
    // skip this one
```